# How to print to C++Builder output window

Tags: delphi, debugging, ide, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I have a C++Builder 2010 project and want to add tests to it. So, instead of pausing the output of my console window to read the outcome of the tests, I want to print the same information to the Output Window in C++Builder (not in the Event Log).

So OutputDebugString is not an option for me. Is there some specific way to either redirect console output to the Output Window or to print directly there?

[image: C++ Builder 2010 output window]

Comment: **printf** prints in the console window, not in the IDE Output Window

Comment: I believe there's an example of what you want to do in the sample code that comes with C++ Builder.  At least there was one available when I was using it 7+ years ago.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the output is a TVirtualStringTree, so, in theory, you should be able to send a message to add a new "line"

Comment: There should be a class/function for this, because C++Builder has an extensive Tool API, but I can't find it so far

Comment: You'll need `IOTAMessageServices::AddCompilerMessage `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply define a Post-build event in your Project Options to run your executable. Its console output will automatically be included in Output messages.

Comment: Well, that would do it, but it would seem unlikely that you really wanted to run the program every single time it was built.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case, at least for C++Builder 2010.

Comment: @riot_starter: I just tested it in C++Builder 2010. It worked as expected.

Comment: @riot_starter What you would have to do is get your program to write output to stdout. That would then be redirected to the compiler output window.

Answer (score 1):

That window is for the output of the compilation process. It's not what you are looking for. You want to generate output whilst the program runs. I'd use the console or OutputDebugString or similar and I can't understand what you have against those options.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I you have any doubt about the meaning of the question, please do not hurry to give an answer, request a clarification in the comment instead. Thanks for understanding :-)

Comment: @user539484 Oh, I misunderstood the question. What did I get wrong. I thought the question was how to write to the compiler output window whilst the program was running. Is that understanding wrong?

Comment: It's just a matter of convenience. Since I want it just for the results of my unit tests, I prefer them in the Output window (so I can see everything related to the build in the same window, not in two separate).

Comment: You'll hate TOndrej's answer as soon as your tests take more than a few seconds to run. Then you'll just do a quick compile to check that your latest code builds and have to wait while they run.

Comment: It should not be a problem, because I have divided my project into two executables (the real one and the tests), so I can compile them separated or together, depending on what I need. In this case the tests will be run only if I compile them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you can define the Post-build event for a specific configuration, say, TestConfig. Then you can switch between Release, Debug, TestConfig as needed.

Comment: @TOndrej Yes you could do that. I'd just add {$IFOPT D+}Readln{$ENDIF} to the end of the .dpr file and be done with it. Anyway, each to their own.